Create child record after parent recorded in the same flow - Screen flow
thank you for your time.
We have 2 custom objects: "Account Forecast" and "Customer Priority." "Account Forecast" is a lookup to the "Accounts" object, and "Customer Priority" is a child to the "Account Forecast" custom object.
I am working on a screen flow where, upon clicking on a button from the Account page, an "Account Forecast" record should be created. As a continuation to the flow, once a user fills in the "Account Forecast" information, the next screen should take them to the "Customer Priority" screen, which should be linked to the "Account Forecast" record created above, using a ScreenFlow.
Here is how I tried to build it:

Get Accounts - store the Account Id from where the flow started.
Screen Element to create an Account Forecast.
Create element to create an Account Forecast record.
Screen Element to create Customer Priority.
I took the loop element because I used repeaters element as there can one Customer priority records created at the same time.

I am getting an error saying "Account Forecast" name is required because of the Master-Detail Relationship between "Account Forecast" and "Customer Priority."
How can I pass the recordId created to step 3 to a variable?


How can I pass the recordId created to step 3 to a variable?

You don't need to store it in a separate variable.
Just reference the Id field of the same record variable that was used to create "Account Forecast" record. And directly assign its value to the master-detail field on a Customer Priority record, on the step "Set Customer Priority"(as per attached screenshot).
Reason: After a successful Create Records step, record Id of the newly created record gets automatically populated on the same record (single/collection) variable, under field Id.
